# сделать проверку на все элементы в методе each библиотеке jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, foreach, index

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="t">
<input type="text" class="t">
<input type="text" class="t">




<script>
   $('.t').on('keyup', function () {

     let each = $('.t').each(function (i, el) {
        let val= $(el).val();

        if (val.length >= 1) {
            console.log('Hello World!');
        }
     })
  })
</script>
```

Мне нужно проверить введено ли значение во всех трех инпутах, только тогда в консоль должно выводится Hello World!. Я хотел попробовать if значение первого элемента && значение второго элемента && значение третьего элемента >= 1 тогда вызывать консоль, но я не пойму как выбрать определенный элемент, нид хелп гайз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.t').on('keyup', function() {
  var hasEmpty = false;
  let each = $('.t').each(function(i, el) {
    if (!$(el).val())
      hasEmpty = true;
  });
  if (!hasEmpty)
    console.log('Hello World!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="t">
<input type="text" class="t">
<input type="text" class="t">
```

Comment: спасибо Игорь )

Answer (score 2):

Просто для инфы... В современных браузерах, незачем использовать перебор для такой простой проверки - селектором с `:[in]valid` она выполняется быстрее и удобнее... А также, с ним легко можно порадовать пользователя обратной связью через цвет:

```js
$('.t').on('keyup', function() {
  if (!$('.t:invalid').length)
    console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

```css
.t { margin-bottom: 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; outline: none; }
.t:focus { border-color: #abf; }
.t:valid { border-color: #9d0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="t" required><br>
<input class="t" required><br>
<input class="t" required>
```

Все что нужно, это добавить атрибут `required`.
Для более сложных проверок, можно указать шаблон валидации регуляркой в атрибуте `pattern`.

Comment: Спасибо  большое!